# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - Compile error with Boost and Sockets.io (C++)

Tags: c++, xcode, sockets, c++11, boost

This is a problem I've been having for a solid week now; I am fairly new to C++ programming and am trying to compile the very basics of the socket.io C++ library in **xcode 6**.

This is the **code** I am using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "sio_client.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    sio::client h;
    h.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
}
```

The **build settings** under target are:
Library search path: `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib`
User Header search path: `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include`, `"$(SRCROOT)/boost/socket.io-client-cpp/lib/websocketpp"`and `"$(SRCROOT)/boost/socket.io-client-cpp/lib/rapidjson/include"`

I have **installed Boost** using `brew install boost --c++11` and imported the `libc++.dylib` and tried the `libc++.6.0.9.dylib` as frameworks into the project.

And I am getting the following compiling error.

[image: Compiling error.]

Note: following tutorial from - https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp.

Can anybody PLEASE! Help me, I am dying here :P

Comment: Does the `"sio_client.h"` header file also contain the *implementation* of call class member functions? Are you missing linking with a library? Are you missing including a source file in your project?

Comment: **Does the "sio_client.h" header file also contain the implementation of call class member functions?**
If you mean the cpp files associated with it then yes.

**Are you missing linking with a library?** 
Maybe? I don't know which libraries I would have to add as i already have the boost lib in the library path.

**Are you missing including a source file in your project?**
As far as I am aware I am not, there are also no errors in the IDE, as in it recognises all the classes and methods being called on it.

Comment: The source files (the `.cpp` files) are separate from the header file. Just because you include the header file doesn't mean that the source files will be automatically included into your project or built and linked. Either build the library as a library that you link with (just like you link with the Boost libraries), or include the source file in the project so the IDE will build them for you.

Comment: That worked! thansk :D